# Ethyl Acetate and other Solvents in a mixture: miscibility and stability

Tags: alcohols, solvents, mixtures, ethers

I was wondering about a heterogeneous solvent mixture containing multiple alcohols such as IPA, Ethanol, methanol etc.  Would EtOAc (Ethyl Acetate) play nice in these mixtures at low volumes such as 1 - 2 % of these mixture combos?  IPA +EtOAc, Eth+EtOAc, Meth+EtOac IPA+Eth+EtOAc, IPA+Eth+Meth+EtOAc. So EtAOc would be very low volume in each of these mixtures.  would it be miscible and fairly stable under normal conditions, ie, no acid, no heat, annhydrous etc.  Any problems that are seen with this?

Comment: I do not see one at least at a quick examination. I assume you have some reasons to add such a small amount

Comment: @Alchimista Thank you for the response.  That would be a starting point to add, or the byproduct/residue of another reaction.  what about at volumes of 5% and 10% that would be more deliberate?

Comment: You can always mix them. A quick experiment need just the solvents and a test tube. Consider that ethyl acetate is very flammable but this goes with safety concerns. No one knows what you have to do. I was just speaking about the mixing itself.